# Show preview of positions

Tags: joomla-3.x, positions

When I create a module I can select its position between many possibilities. Is there a way to preview all these positions in the page in order to know the place where the module will be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see them from adminitration doing this steps:

- In the top menu, click Extensions and then click Template Manager
- In the tabs at the top of the page, click the Options tab
- Under the Templates tab, find the following setting:

Enable: Preview Module Positions

- Once again, in the top menu, click Extensions and then click Template Manager
  Now that we have the Preview Module Positions setting enabled, you will see a preview icon next to your Site Templates.
- Click the preview icon next to the template you would like to view.

Hope this help you

Answer (score 2):

I've found a solution by myself.

1. Go to **Extension->Templates**
2. Click on **Options** button (top-right page corner)
3. Enable the option **Enable Module Positions**
4. Save changes
5. Go again to **Extension->Templates** and select **Templates** on the left menu
6. Click the **Preview** link for the desired template

The page appears with all position shown.

Another option is to append **&tp=1** (or **&tp=1** if in the link there are other parameters) to the page for which you want to see positions. Also in this case the **Enable Module Positions** must be enabled.